# Cоздание релиза программы с базой данных в Qt

Tags: sqlite, qt, c++

Поясните, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать релиз. Вроде все просто, но создав его, программа не подключается к бд (`sqlite`). Искал, гуглил, куча разных методов. Где-то написано, что нужно 'Qt' с 'sqlite' пересобрать, где-то еще что-то, не понятно. Можете объяснить, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать релиз. За одно и на ХэшКоде появится нормальная статья, как это сделать.

Comment: Вы смотрели в дебаггере, что именно не получается сделать у вашей программы? Не находит файл БД? Это самый короткий путь в поиске проблемы.
P.S. дебаг и релиз компилируются в разные папки?

Comment: У программы не получается загрузить драйвер QSQLITE. Извиняюсь за то что сразу не уточнил это. Да дебаг и релиз в разные папки компилируются.

Comment: А сам этот драйвер физически доступен скомпилированной программе? Он рядом лежит, или в PATH прописан, или еще где?

Кстати, как вариант могу предложить с помощью DependancyWalker загрузить этот драйвер и проверить, какие ему самому нужны dll - может банально чего-то не хватает.

Comment: Скомпилированной программе он не доступен, иначе бы все работало я так понимаю, вот как сделать что бы он был доступен на любом компе мне не понятно

Comment: @enum, рецепт простой: собрать/раздобыть подходящий релизный модуль SQLite-драйвера для Qt, а затем подложить его в bin-папку с релизными файлами, с помощью того же make-файла, который собирает ваш проект. Ну и распространять программу также придется с ним, как и с остальными Qt*** нужными библиотеками.

Если файл есть драйвера есть, но все равно не работает, проверьте его зависимости с помощью DependancyWalker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как всегда, все оказалось просто. Нужно создать в папке с релизным exe'шником папку `sqldrivers` и вставить туда файл `qsqlite4.dll`. Но есть разница какой версии этот файл. У меня не работает с 4.7.4.0 (Он вместе с Qt 2.4.1), заработало только с 4.5.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, вам надо понимать, что каждая БД `SQLITE` представлена не в виде некой СУБД на подобии `MySQL`, а как отдельный файл (часто вообще без всякого расширения). Но это вам однозначно известно, раз работаете с `SQLITE`. А вот для работы с этим типом баз данных в `QT`, вам необходимо подключить библиотеку (не знаю, делали ли вы так...):

```
#include <QtSql>
```

**[Подробнее здесь.](http://cpp-qt.at.ua/news/qt_i_raboty_s_bazami_dannykh_sqlite/2012-04-27-2)**

Comment: Конечно делал, моя программа правильно находит и работает с бд в дебаге. В релизе не могу добиться подобного же.

Answer (score 0):

Не работал с Qt, но подозреваю, что проблема в настройках линкера. Для того что бы работать с `sqlite` нужна библиотека, в режиме разработки она берется из самого `Qt`, но при компиляции в релиз, линкер не ложит её в проект. В общем, надо это дело настроить. Если дело под Виндой то можно просто найти сам `dll` файл и кинуть его в папку с программой.

Comment: Пробовал, но все равно не работает.